# Call 'invoke.js 'fails in 'Writing Your First Application' official section

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

every one,

I follow the Hyperledger Fabric v1.2 doc to build the fabcar application.

The network can set up and be queried successfully.
However, when i calling 'node invoke.js', the following error pops up.

```
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
Assigning transaction_id:  a9a75de658c14f487d8a57b110d472d2b73471e24af0fa95159048ec39ae7242
Transaction proposal was good
Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - 200, message - ""
Failed to invoke successfully :: TypeError: fabric_client.newEventHub is not a function
```

From my search on relevant questions, I fix the grpc version to 1.9.1, but didn't resolve it.

This is my updated package.json file.

```
  1 {
  2     "name": "fabcar",
  3     "version": "1.0.0",
  4     "description": "Hyperledger Fabric Car Sample Application",
  5     "main": "fabcar.js",
  6     "scripts": {
  7         "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  8     },
  9     "dependencies": {
 10         "fabric-ca-client": "unstable",
 11         "fabric-client": "unstable",
 12         "grpc": "1.9.1"
 13     },
 14     "author": "Anthony O'Dowd",
 15     "license": "Apache-2.0",
 16     "keywords": [
 17         "Hyperledger",
 18         "Fabric",
 19         "Car",
 20         "Sample",
 21         "Application"
 22     ]
 23 }
```

Any idea to solve this problem? I guess it should be the version problem related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version mis-match with the fabric-client. The EventHub was deprecated in release 1.1.0 and removed in v1.2.0 To fix the problem (until I submit and merge a formal fix to the samples) please change the `fabcar/package.json` file as follows and re-run `npm install` to install the v1.2.1 of the `fabric-client` and `fabric-ca-client` packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "fabric-ca-client": "1.2.1",
    "fabric-client": "1.2.1",
    "grpc": "^1.6.0"
},
```